# States of a qubit in a DC-SQUID

Tags: quantum-state, experimental-realization, superconducting-quantum-computing

Does anybody of you know what are the two states $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ of a qubit in a DC-SQUID (2 Josephson junctions in a loop)?